# Selecting particular fields in MongooseJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a NodeJS application with Mongoose ODM.
I want to select three particular fields from a collection.
Example my collection is "Users" having fields '_id','username','email','usertype','password'...
I want to select only 'username','email'&'usertype' .
This was **my code**

```
 var query = models.User.find({}).select('UserName', 'Email', 'UserType');
```

This was working fine with mongoose 2 version,I updated to Mongodb 2.2 and Mongoose 3.3.1.
Now I am getting error

```
500 TypeError: Invalid select() argument. Must be a string or object.
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since mongoose 3 [select()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) parameter can be either:

- an object containing 0-1 map of excluded/included fields
- a space delimited string of fieldnames (with `-` before fields that need to be excluded)

So you should either use:

```
var query = models.User.find({}).select('UserName Email UserType');
```

or

```
var query = models.User.find({}).select({UserName : 1, Email : 1, UserType: 1});
```

Answer (score 14):

As of Mongoose version 4, you don't need select().

```
var query = models.User.find({}, 'UserName Email UserType');
```